# how to auto share link to facebook

Tags: share, facebook-likebox

I have a link http://news.bamlike.com/index.php. When i click on link to view article.

if you has loged in facebook and accecpt with some permission in this apps. 
It'll auto share that link on facebook timeline (Activity
Recent) .It's like you're just click like it.

demo image: http://tapchidesign.hostoi.com/help2.jpg

How can i do it ?
Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 1):

On each page load, check if the logged in user has authenticated your app. If they have, publish an open graph built-in "read" action. Read the [documentation about built-in actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/built-in-actions/)