# How to auto share a post on facebook timeline?

Tags: php, facebook, share

I have a website that uses the Group Buying Site plugin (http://groupbuyingsite.com). It uses facebook app to login and register.

When I add a new item to the cart the user is redirected to `cart.php` and the function `add_item($product_id, ...)` is called. I want to know if there is a way that when I enter this page I automatically share a post on facebook timeline.

Thanks.

Comment: I have read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14072506/how-to-auto-share-link-to-facebook) but it didn't help me. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the access token, I suggest you try this:

```
$result = $facebook->api(
    '/me/feed/',
    'post',
    array('access_token' => $access_token, 'message' => 'Your Post here')
);
```

Comment: This will work if you have the user has granted you the publish_actions permission, but even then it's against Facebook TOS to post to a user stream without asking for it every time.

Comment: Really helped. Just had to merge the Facebook SDK with the GBS Facebook class.

Comment: @SankalpMishra:is it possible now?

Comment: @OPUS Now its possible

Comment: @SankalpMishra:hey..can we have a chat?

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37811/facebook-auto-sharingsome-api

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $facebook->api(
    '/me/feed/',
    'post',
    array('access_token' => $access_token, 'message' => 'Your Post here')
```

Comment: Would explain a bit your answer